# PHP unlink permission denied error

Tags: php, file

I have used `php GD library` to resize images and store them on local first.

After resize i upload those images to `server`.

I want to delete images from local directory now.

Here is my code..

```
          $image_name = $_FILES["imagePath"]["name"];
            $newimg = 'app/templates/'.TEMPLATE.'/memberimages/'.$image_name;

           $filename = realpath($newimg);

            if (is_file($filename)) {

                chmod($filename, 0777);

                if (unlink($filename)) {
                   echo 'File deleted';
                } else {
                   echo 'Cannot remove that file';
                }

             } else {
               echo 'File does not exist';
             }
```

But I am getting `Permission denied` error at `unlink`

I checked `memberimages` folder with `php is_writable()` which return true as well.

I tried with `exec()` as well. No error but unable to delete image.

Need Help.

`If I am able to save images in that folder then delete should work as well. Is it really permissions related issue?`

Comment: The folder needs to have executable permissions, and clearly it doesn't.

Comment: Check that uploaded file is owned by the same system user that runs your PHP script, (usually "www", "httpd", or "apache").

Comment: How to check user?

Comment: @AD7six I checked with `is_writable` for folder. return true. Also added `0777` to folder as well still not working

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the file that you are trying to pass to `unlink()` / delete is not being opened. If the file is `.exe` or etc please also check in *Windows Task Manager -> Process* and then kill it (in this case i think the file is image).
2. Change permission status of file. Maybe you can't have access to delete the file (execute permission).

After you sure the file is not being opened [1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php), then lets try this code :

```
// Check existence of file
if (file_exists($cekFile1)) {
    // make sure you have permission to delete file
    if(chmod($fileDir, 0777)){
        if(!unlink($cekFile1)){
            echo "unlink is fail !";
        }
    }else{
        echo "chmod is fail";
    }
    // owner have read, write, execute rights.
    // owner's user group only have read rights.
    // everybody else only have read rights.
    chmod($fileDir, 0744);

}
```

For more information about `chmod()`, please check this reference:

[php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php).

[php-cmod-function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-chmod-function/).